# Positioning of two elements

Tags: html, css

There are two blocks in which there is a text of variable length
It is necessary that one block is on the right side, and the second block is attached to it. and if the second block has a large text, then it was moved to the line below.

```
<div style="text-align:right;">
    <span>
      You are logged on as a user <span>{username}</span>

         {sometext}
          | <a href="#">Change password</a>
          | <a href="#">Exit</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I tried to do so.

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <span>
      <div style="position:absolute; right: 250px;">
        You are logged on as a user <span>{username}</span>
      </div>
      <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;">
        {someText}
          | <a href="#">Change password</a>
          | <a href="#">Exit</a>
      </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

But nothing happened, the block with the user's name rides on the right block
How to make so that blocks did not run into each other and the text was transferred to a new line if it does not enter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your goal is easy to achieve with flexbox. The items will stay aligned to the right and if they cannot fit in one line some of them will be moved to the next line.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    You are logged on as a user <span>{username}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  {someText}
  | <a href="#">Change password</a>
  | <a href="#">Exit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend using this `flexbox` answer, my answer below was trying to use the setup he knew with positioning and such but is not as good going forward: as `flexbox` replaces these old school ways of positioning it is really the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<div style="position:relative; float: right;">
  <div style="position:relative; right: 0;">
    You are logged on as a user <span>{username}</span>
  </div>
  <div style="position:relative; top:0; right:0;">
    {someText}
      | <a href="#">Change password</a>
      | <a href="#">Exit</a>
  </div>
```

The float gets it over to the right and the positioning gets things onto the next line like you need.